# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '... modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am working with React Native Navigation and when I navigate under one stack (open the screen in that stack or any nested stacks and so on through stack, if there any) I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'myProject\http:\10.0.2.2:8081\index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.appName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at getCodeFrame (myProject\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (myProject\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:992:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (myProject\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'myProject\\http:\\10.0.2.2:8081\\index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.appName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
}
```

Version of packages:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
"@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

My hierarchy is as follow (if it matters):

```
- BottomTabNav
  - Home
  - User profile (Stack)
    - Screen1
    - Screen2 (Stack)
      - Screen2.1
    ...
```

User profile.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { View } from "react-native";
import ScreenNames from "../../../../app/configs/routerConfig";
import { UserProfileStackParamList } from "../../../../common/types/Stacks";
import UserProfileScreen from "./screens/UserProfileScreen";
import UserProfileEditScreen from "./screens/UserProfileEditScreen";
import UserProfileLanguageScreen from "./screens/sections/userSettings/UserProfileLanguageScreen";
import FeedbackScreen from "./screens/sections/feedback/FeedbackScreen";

// Type checking the screens
// Also using ScreenNames which is just a big enum with screen names
const Stack = createStackNavigator<UserProfileStackParamList>();

const UserProfileStack: React.FC = () => (
    <View>
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={ScreenNames.UserProfile}
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen
                name={ScreenNames.UserProfile}
                component={UserProfileScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name={ScreenNames.UserProfileEdit}
                component={UserProfileEditScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name={ScreenNames.UserProfilePersonalInformation}
                component={UserProfilePersonalInformationScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name={ScreenNames.Feedback}
                component={FeedbackScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </View>
);

export default UserProfileStack;
```

Any pointers (pun not intended) would be helpful